# Не могу никак подписать Андроид Студио приложение с помощью pepk.jar?

Tags: java, android-studio, alias, keystore

За два дня так и не смог подписать приложение с помощью **pepk.jar** !

Примеров нет! Или не нашел (май 2017)

Не понятно четко что и как вписывать в --keystore=? --alias=? --output=?

Вот инструкция от Google:

> С помощью команды ниже запустите инструмент, который экспортирует и
>   зашифрует закрытый ключ. Не забудьте заменить аргументы, выделенные
>   жирным шрифтом. Когда потребуется, введите пароли хранилища и ключа.
>
> $ java -jar pepk.jar --keystore=**foo.keystore** --alias=**foo**
>   --output=**encrypted_private_key_path** --encryptionkey=eb10fe8f7c7c9df715022017b00c6471f8ba8170b13049a11e6c09ffe3056a104a3bbe4ac5a955f4ba4fe93fc8cef27558a3eb9d2a529a2092761fb833b656cd48b9de6a

Вот как я делал (1):

```
java -jar pepk.jar --keystore=D:\KEY_ET --alias=ET --output=D:\newkey.pem  --encryptionkey=rb10fe8f7c7c9df715022017b00c6471f8ba8170b13049a11e6c09ffe3056a104a3bbe4ac5a955f4ba4fe93fc8cef27558a3eb9d2a529a2092761fb833b65643567894re
Enter store password:
Error: D:\KEY_ET (Отказано в доступе)
```

Еще так пробовал (2):

```
java -jar pepk.jar --keystore=D:\KEY_ET\key.jks --alias=ET --output=D:\newkey.pem --encryptionkey=rb10fe8f7c7c9df715022017b00c6471f8ba8170b13049a11e6c09ffe3056a104a3bbe4ac5a955f4ba4fe93fc8cef27558a3eb9d2a529a2092761fb833b65643567894re
Enter store password:
Enter key password:
Error: No key for alias: ET
```

Само приложение подписывается в Android Studio без проблем и публикуется на Google Play без проблем!

**D:\KEY_ET** - папка с ключами,
**key.jks** - ключ,
создаваемые Android Studio по команде Generate Signed APK...

P.S.
Вот здесь: 
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44103024/how-to-enable-google-play-app-signing]
есть разъяснения, с учетом их делал, вроде, все правильно...

Видимо, проблема с "Отказано в доступе". Запускался как Администратор и не как Администратор... Перестраивал права доступа к папке с ключами D:\KEY_ET .

Ничего не помогает!

Comment: На [английском SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оказалось!

**Правильный был второй вариант записи. Только надо было писать алиас маленькими буквами: et** . Хотя у меня алиас внутри Андроид Студии был создан как ET (т.е. заглавными буквами) и работал в Андроид Студии нормально и без предупреждений!!!

Вот правильный синтаксис:

> java -jar pepk.jar --keystore=**D:\KEY_ET\key.jks** --alias=**et**
>   --output=**D:\newkey.pem** --encryptionkey=rb10fe8f7c7c9df715022017b00c6471f8ba8170b13049a11e6c09ffe3056a104a3bbe4ac5a955f4ba4fe93fc8cef27558a3eb9d2a529a2092761fb833b65643567894re

Советую разработчикам **Android Studio** и утилиты **pepk.jar** обратить на это внимание! И выдавать соответствующие предупреждения на стадии подписывания внутри Андроид Студии и во время работы утилиты pepk.jar!

P.S. Оказалось как всегда все очень просто, но попробуй сразу догадаться, что алиас, названный в Андроид Студии ЗАГЛАВНЫМИ БУКВАМИ в pepk.jar надо писать строчными)))

Comment: До вас просто никто не пробовал называть алиасы заглавными буквами

Comment: Если я разработчик с многолетним стажем сделал это, значит таких еще найдется ) И помочь им надо!!! А система даже никак не реагировала на это! Ни как! И очень опытный программер, который был рядом никак тоже на это не реагировал, когда помогал искать мне ошибку! Не надо, господа-товарищи, заносится, что никто!!! Все всегда могут допускать несуразные ошибки!

Comment: Ты бы еще на кириллице написал, а потом искал ошибку. Если так печет, то напиши им в багтрекер, а не сюда.

Comment: Я просто делюсь опытом. В такую ситуацию могут другие люди попасть тоже!

Comment: @user_MGU добрый день! не могли бы вы мне помочь с моим вопросом по цифровой подписи? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/958072/google-play-market-%D0%A4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B2-google-play-%D0%B8-jks-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB