# Google Play Market, Функция подписания приложений в Google Play и JKS-файл

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, keystore

Заливаю свое приложение в Google Play Market и нужна помощь, чтобы разобраться в цифровой подписи.

Я сделал app-release.apk и создал для него свой JKS-файл (все через IntelliJ IDEA). Загрузил свою *apk в Google консоль.  JKS сохранил в надежном месте.

Мне сейчас там выдает следующее:

```
Функция подписания приложений в Google Play включена для этого приложения

Сертификат для подписи приложения СКАЧАТЬ СЕРТИФИКАТ

Загрузка сертификата СКАЧАТЬ СЕРТИФИКАТ
```

Объясните, что мне делать с этими сертификатами, которые предлагает скачать консоль?

Что мне надо будет делать, когда я захочу обновить это приложение?

UP:

То, что я накосячил малость - я понял. Буду пересоздавать проект (хорошо, что не опубликовал его еще).

Сейчас стоит вопрос по цифровой подписи: что выбирать и как? Понятно, что не #1 (уже плавали, знаем) и не #2 (это первое приложение).

Что из себя представляют #3/4 ? Есть ли смысл их выбирать или вообще отказаться от Гугловской помощи с ключами и самому вести их с помощью созданного мной в IntelliJ IDEA *JKS?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Прошло 8 дней.
Вообщем я решил "отклонить" предложение Гугла в помощи. Залил приложение - все хорошо.

На моей телефоне стояла версия 1.0. в Гугл залил версию 1.1. Play Market видит, что это приложение у меня есть, но не предлагает обновить.

Сегодня залил новую версию 1.2, использовал свой старый ключ подписи. Все прошло на отлично. Play Market обновил у меня в телефоне прилагу.

Проводил тесты на телефоне. На нем была скачена версия с Play Market 1.1. Потом проводились тесты (шнур к компу и запуск приложение через Idea). И когда пришло обнволение в Play Market - он обновился.

Вывод: лучше использовать свой JKS и полностью контролировать приложение.

p.s. автоматически не обновилось из-за параметра "versionCode" который был одинаковый. при загрузке в Play Market каждого нового apk надо увеличивать этот параметр (гугл вам сам напомнит, если забудете)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы неосторожно согласились на подписывание приложения ключом, хранящимся у гугла.

Тот ключ что у вас - не настоящий ключ, но временный, которым вы можете подписывать приложение для загрузки в PlayMarket. Если ключ не совпадает (с тем, которым вы в первый раз подписывали APK при отправке его гуглу) то загрузить не удастся. В этом случае вам надо будет запросить у гугла новый ключ для подписывания приложения. Это полезно, т.к. вы можете теперь потерять ваш ключ и продолжать иметь возможность загружать обновления.

Минусы в том, что теперь вы не имеете полного контроля над подписыванием приложения. Если что-то случится с ключом на стороне гугла - вы не сможете обновить приложение. Но это маловероятно. Более вероятно что гугл по какой-то причине удалит ваше приложение. В этом случае вы не сможете послать юзерам обновления через другой канал (по почте, например), т.к. у вас нет ключа для подписи приложения и ОС будет воспринимать ваш APK не как обновление имеющегося. Т.е. при установке будет полностью удалена вся информация из предыдущей версии.

Так же, если вы используете всякие сторонние API (например для авторизации) вам надо вместо двух отпечатков ключей указывать 3 - дебажный, релизный (тот что у вас) и отпечаток ключа PlayMarket (тот что у гугла). Это выливается в то, что вы теперь не можете локально получить APK аналогичный по подписи тому, что получат юзеры и протестировать его.

Отменить подписывание приложения гуглом нельзя.

Comment: хорошо. с этим понятно. вопрос: что надо выбирать в след.раз (я так понимаю, эта привязка идет на весь аккаунт?) чтобы иметь полный контроль над приложением?

Comment: @Wlad, вроде бы такое привязывается для приложения, не аккаунта. В следующий раз надо очень аккуратно читать всё что пишет гугл при выкладывании APK. Там можно, жамкая по незаметным кнопочкам отказаться от навязывания этого. Точно не скажу - давно не создавал новых приложений)

Comment: просто я его еще не опубликовал. я все подготовил и меня смутил этот раздел с сертификатами. сейчас попробовал создать новый проект. есть возможность "(Дополнительные настройки) Предоставить ключ подписи, который Google Play будет использовать для этого приложения" "продолжить / отказаться"

Comment: @Wlad, ага, похоже на то что нужно, но я точно не уверен) Они вообще могут забрать такую возможность в любой момент)

Comment: внес up в основной топик. подскажите чего умного)

Comment: @Wlad, кажется тут вам надо нажать на `Отключить` чтобы гугл ничего такого не предлагал. Во всяком случае вам точно не подходят первые 2 пункта.

Comment: выходит, что эта функция - лишь пересоздание и хранение ключа? большой никакой полезности она в себе не несет? если я на 100% уверен, что мой JKS я не потеряю, я могу ее отключить?

Comment: @Wlad, примерно так, да. Вы передоверяете хранение ключа гуглу в обмен на потерю контроля. Если вы уверены в том, что можете сохранить свой ключ - отказывайтесь от этого предложения. Если, конечно, вам нравится контроль над собственным приложением)

Comment: я не совсем понимаю, что из себя представляет "контроль" над приложением. и что надо делать, если я все же доверюсь вести этот "контроль" Гуглу при следующих обновлениях приложения.

Comment: @Wlad, под контролем я подразумеваю возможность выдавать юзерам APK для обновления в обход PlayMarket. Если у вас нет ключа - вы не сможете обновить приложение, только удалить и поставить другое, т.к. будут отличаться отпечатки ключа. Если вы хотите довериться гуглу - вам надо отправлять ему APK подписанную вашим ключом. Гугл же у себя уберёт ваш ключ и заменит его на свой. Т.е. по сути процесс создания и загрузки APK в обоих случаях не отличается. А вот юзеры получат из PlayMarket приложения подписанные разными ключами.

Comment: большое спасибо, что так развернуто наотвечали мне тут. буду искать дальше информацию. склоняюсь к вашей "независимой от Гугла" позиции))