# Как подписать APK с помощью Google Play?

Tags: android, apk, google-play-console

Столкнулся с проблемой при подписании приложения для загрузки в **Play Market**. В общем, я подключил подпись приложения в Google Play. Скачал сертификат подписи, но что дальше? Я уже создавал АРК с подписью, генерируя ключ в Android Studio. Но при загрузке ошибка, сертификаты подписи не совпадают, я понимаю что я что то опустил. Подскажите что я не сделал или что сделал не так.

Comment: Вы загружаете новое приложение или обновляете старое ?

Comment: @GinTasan Новое

Comment: Для вашего проложения был создан сертификат загрузки ? Если нет, необходимо загрузить APK файл, подписанный ключом, который вам дали раннее

Comment: @GinTasan, да сертификат загрузки создан

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/958072/google-play-market-%D0%A4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B2-google-play-%D0%B8-jks-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB вот ссылка, где мне помогли разобраться "зачем вообще нужен ключ подписи от Гугла". это оффтоп, конечно, но может вы передумаете использовать Гугловскую подпись.

Comment: @Wlad спасибо за информацию, наверное буду все таки свой ключ юзать

Comment: @Wlad а Вы исполюзете свой ключ или гугловский?

Comment: свой использую. проблем с ним никаких нет. приложение обновлял, все хорошо гугл принял.